# ASP.Net getting a list of querystrings from a link

Tags: asp.net

I have a web application that is using [UrlRewriting](http://urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html). Now I want to set it that if the user enters the page with a url in re-written format, all the links apply the same format, otherwise they remain the same (with normal query strings).

Is there a way that I can get a list of query strings that are in the links without parsing the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring.aspx)